# How to create instance of a DataSet by String Name?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

I am creating a dynamic report viewer in ASP.Net (VB.Net) that loads an RDLC dynamically, and all is working as they are supposed to.
The only problem I am having is when I try to create an instance of a DataSet using its string name in order to populate the report data accordingly.

Below is the code I have been trying to run with no luck:

```
    Dim MyInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("ClassList"))
    MyInstance = GetReportData()
    Dim datasource As New ReportDataSource(FID, MyInstance.Tables(FID))
    rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
```

GetType is always returning Nothing and thus CreateInstance throws an error.
Below is the code that works fine:

```
    Dim MyInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(ClassList))
    MyInstance = GetReportData()
    Dim datasource As New ReportDataSource(FID, MyInstance.Tables(FID))
    rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Could you clarify what is string name? Are you trying to create DataSet with specific columns?

Comment: "ClassList" is the name of the existing DataSet (ClassList.xsd) that resides in the App_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

I basically had the same scenario where i want to dynamically load a report (chosen by the user) into the SSRS Web Viewer.  I do this by convention.  Everyone knows to use the default DataSet1, DataSet2, 3, 4, ...  Other then that ... i don't know how to ask the RDLC report what the given name of the Datasource is?  I suppose, being that RDLC is just XML you could parse it to find out.  But regardless, I just go by simple convention.

```
class DynamicLoadingRDLC
{
    protected static System.Data.DataSet rptds = null;
    private void loadRDLReport(UDParamters pprms, ICustomRDL rdl)
    {

        this.ButtonDownloadReport.Enable();
        this.PanelMain.AutoScroll = false;

        if (rdl == null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to load report!");


        if (rdl == null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to cast report!");

        // returns a dataset from the selected report
        var ds = rdl.ReportData(me.Clinician, Context, pprms);

        // set the dataset into the static class ... we need this if this report has a subreport
        rptds = ds;

        // register the callback for subreports
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SetSubDataSource);

        // reset the viewer
        this.ReportViewer1.Reset();



        /*
        You can get more then 1 table added to a report.  Tables will be ordered by name.  Each will be added as DataSet1,2,3,4...
        Code your RDLC and XSD accordingly...
        */
        for (int i = 0; i < rptds.Count(); i++)
        {
                Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource src = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet" + (i + 1), rptds.Tables[i]);
                e.DataSources.Add(src);
        }

        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "custom/" + rdl.RDLFile();
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }

        public void SetSubDataSource(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rptds == null)
                return;



            for (int i = 0; i < rptds.Count(); i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource src = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet" + (i + 1), rptds.Tables[i]);
                e.DataSources.Add(src);
            }
        }

}
```